# Is it possible to detect URL changes with document.visiblityState?

Tags: javascript, url, single-page-application

I saw a lot of articles that say "Beforeunload is bad for mobile. Use visibilityState instead."

So I tried use `document.visibilityState` like this:

```
 useEffect(()=>{ 
   document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', ()=>{console.log('test')},false)
 },[]);
```

I see this code works when I change tabs and it works when I refresh the page which is great, but it does not work when I change URL manually. Should I use `beforeUnload`  instead of `visibilitychange` ?

`router.events`  do not work either because changing url manually in url is not SPA ...

Comment: If you are specifically looking to trap the event raised when the user leaves the page (for any reason, clicking a link, typing a new URL etc.) then you would need to use `beforeunload`, not `visibilitychange`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am looking for both actually. Better to say all possible scenarios. Leaving, Refreshing, Switching tabs, Closing,  Apps etc. So I have to use both `beforeunload`  and `visibilitychange` ?

Comment: Yep - use both in that case. It would be worth extracting the common logic to it's own function which can be invoked from both events to keep your code DRY